# how to compare the result of 2 queries and get the values that match

Tags: mysql, sql

basically what I need to do is to concatenate some values in a table, group by the new concatenated result to apply the SUM function and after that I want to search the concatenated values in another table where I have to apply the same concat function and be able to compare the values and for the values that match return a column value

so far I've created this query but I can not return the column I want from the second table.

```
SELECT
   `model`,`size`,`color_temp`,`lumen_out`, SUM(`order_qty`),
   CONCAT(`model`,`size`,`color_temp`,`lumen_out`) AS concatenate 
FROM `sales` 
GROUP BY  concatenate, `model`, `size`, `color_temp`,`lumen_out`
HAVING concatenate IN (
  SELECT CONCAT(`model`,`size`,`color_temp`,`lumen_out`) FROM `pcbs`
)
```

what I want to get is something like the following:

```
model  size    color  lumen    qty   concatenate   pcb          
LCL       2     30      ML     93    LCL230ML   93072008-2102
LCL       2     35      ML     57    LCL235ML   93072009-2104
LCL       2     40      ML     66    LCL240ML   93072009-2104
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join two "table expressions" (that act as tables in a `SELECT`) as in:

```
select
  a.*, b.*
from (
  SELECT
    `model`,`size`,`color_temp`,`lumen_out`, SUM(`order_qty`),
    CONCAT(`model`,`size`,`color_temp`,`lumen_out`) AS concatenate 
  FROM `sales` 
  GROUP BY  concatenate, `model`, `size`, `color_temp`,`lumen_out`
) a
join (
  SELECT
    `model`,`size`,`color_temp`,`lumen_out`, SUM(`order_qty`),
    CONCAT(`model`,`size`,`color_temp`,`lumen_out`) AS concatenate 
  FROM `pcbs` 
  GROUP BY  concatenate, `model`, `size`, `color_temp`,`lumen_out`
) b on a.concatenate = b.concatenate
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you concatenate the values for a `join`?  Just use the values as-is.

So:

```
select s.*, p.*
from (select model, size, color_temp, lumen_out, sum(order_qty) as qty
      from sales
      group by model, size, color_temp, lumen_out
     ) s join
     (select model, size, color_temp, lumen_out, sum(order_qty) as qty
      from pcbs
      group by model, size, color_temp, lumen_out
     ) p
     on p.model = s.model and
        p.size = s.size and
        p.color_temp = s.color_temp and
        p.lumen_out = s.lumen_out;
```

This should have better performance as well.

Note that this only keeps rows with a full match in both tables.  If you want *all* rows, then the right construct is a `full join` -- but MySQL does not support that.  There are alternative methods.  Your question, however, suggests that you want only matching rows.

Comment: what happens is that I need to get that concatenated value, thanks for your suggestion

Comment: @oleonides . . . You should still join on the individual columns.